# Unable to programmatically show a Bootstrap Vue modal from a setTimeout() callback

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I'm building a Vue CLI app (Webpack template) that uses Bootstrap Vue to display modal windows. I am trying to programmatically display the modal (see Bootstrap Vue [documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal) for programmatically invoking the modal) from my Vue component's `mounted()` hook like so:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'ButtonComponent',

  mounted() {
    const showModal = sessionStorage.getItem('showModal');
    if (showModal === 'yes') this.$refs.myModal.show();
  }
}
</script>
```

This works just fine. However, I am unable to get this to work if I introduce a `setTimeout()` function like this:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'ButtonComponent',

  mounted() {
    const showModal = sessionStorage.getItem('showModal');
    if (showModal === 'yes') setTimeout(() => this.$refs.myModal.show(), 3500);
  }
}
</script>
```

Why doesn't this display the modal after 3.5 seconds? The timeout works and I know that because I tried `console.log()`-ging a message from it. I figured it could be because the Vue JS instance isn't available inside the timer so I tried declaring a `const self = this;` and calling `setTimeout(() => self.$refs.myModal.show(), 3500);` but that didn't help either. What am I missing here?

Comment: It seems to be working for me: https://jsfiddle.net/70yyx8z2/157/
Are there any errors showing up in console or it just simply doesn't work?

Comment: @dziraf Yes but you seem to have written your own custom modal component. My issue is that I am using the Bootstrap Vue modal: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal/. No errors in the console, it just doesn't seem to work!

Answer (score 1):

Syntactically talking, is correct. When you use arrow functions, *this* is binded to the context from where it was originally called. In your case *this* inside the setTimeout means the Vue instances. Try to do several *console.log* calls like:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(this); // the vue instances
  console.log(this.$refs); // the $refs
  console.log(this.$refs.myModal); // the modal $ref
}, 3500)
```

Just to check that your $ref exists. Maybe your *myModal* component is not binded yet?

Comment: I just logged all three and can confirm that the $ref does exist. I even see the `.show()` method but it just doesn't seem to get executed! Driving me crazy! It's not possible for the modal to not be bound yet because I am calling this script in Vue's `mounted()` hook and it works without the `setTimeout()`. No other error messages in the console either!

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a jsfiddle (or similar)? Maybe, I can help you from there!